# Get element text through GTM Custom JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have two groups of links all with the same class names, the only difference is the text in the .
I need to get the  text for the clicked link and pass it to GA through GTM.

```
<div class="item-set">
  <header>Section Title One</header>
  <section class="products">
    <div class="list">
      <a href="/Product/60216935"><img src="/ProductImages1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <a href="/Product/6021693x"><img src="/ProductImages2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <a href="/Product/6021693y"><img src="/ProductImages3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="item-set">
  <header>Section Title Two</header>
  <section class="products">
    <div class="list">
      <a href="/Product/60216935"><img src="/ProductImages1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <a href="/Product/6021693x"><img src="/ProductImages2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <a href="/Product/6021693y"><img src="/ProductImages3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have created a custom javascript variable

```
function() {
  $('section.products div.list').click(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.item-set').find('header').text();
  });
}
```

But the *bleep* thing isn't working as I expect (or at all). It returns "undefined".

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't bind to `click` event in JS variable. You should use JS variables in GTM **only for receiving values**

The correct way to achieve your goal is:

1) Enable built-in variable Click Element (if you already have it, you can skip this step)
[image]

2) Create trigger, which will fire when you clicking on your links
[image]
CSS selector on the screenshot is `.item-set .list a`

3) Create JS variable
[image]
Code is: `function() {
    return $({{Click Element}}.closest('.item-set')).find('header').text();
}`
3) Create a tag, which will send data to GA
[image]
Here you can use your variable form step 3 `{{Click List Header}}`

Comment: Thanks heaps. Worked like a charm!
I was pretty close to the answer. Just a little off.

Comment: The jquery syntax used here doesn't work with the most recent version of GTM as of July 2019. The correct syntax would be `function() {
    return {{Click Element}}.closest('.item-set').find('header').text();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not capturing/storing the `return $(this).closest('.item-set').find('header').text();` from the function?

When you for example immediately invoke your function and click a div, the text of the `<header>` will be logged to the console.

```js
(function() {
    $('section.products div.list').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // to prevent the default action of the click
        console.log($(this).closest('.item-set').find('header').text());
        return $(this).closest('.item-set').find('header').text();
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-set">
    <header>Section Title One</header>
    <section class="products">
        <div class="list">
            <a href="/Product/60216935"><img src="/ProductImages1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <a href="/Product/6021693x"><img src="/ProductImages2.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <a href="/Product/6021693y"><img src="/ProductImages3.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="item-set">
    <header>Section Title Two</header>
    <section class="products">
        <div class="list">
            <a href="/Product/60216935"><img src="/ProductImages1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <a href="/Product/6021693x"><img src="/ProductImages2.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <a href="/Product/6021693y"><img src="/ProductImages3.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```